# clearInterval for jquery plugin with public method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, clearinterval

I am having a problem with clearing interval inside jquery plugin. The below is simplified code. If I try inside Firefox console to run

```
$('.banner').pluginName().stop()
```

it will keep logging console.log(1). I even tried to use `window.interval` instead of `$wrapper.interval` but still without success. I guess the problem is with scope, but why, isn't window.interval global scope? What would be a proper way to clear interval with public method?

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>                  
      ;(function($, f) {
        $.fn.pluginName= function(o) {
            var $wrapper = this; 
            var init = function(o) {
                $wrapper.start();
                return $wrapper;
            };

            this.start = function() {
                $wrapper.interval = setInterval(function() {
              console.log(1)
                }, 1000);
            };

            //  Stop autoplay
            this.stop = function() {
            console.log(2)
            clearInterval($wrapper.interval);
                return $wrapper;
            };
          return init(o);

        };
      })(window.jQuery, false);
      $('.banner').pluginName();        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried also window instead of $wrapper and it is the same. I don't understand why it is not accessible outside or more importantly what would be a correct way to clear this interval.

Comment: You just need to declare $ wrapper.interval more globally, like outside of this.start and then it should be accessible outside of this.start's scope.

Comment: But $wrapper is already as globally as it can be. I could only put it outside plugin, but then it makes no sense to create plugin if I need to define variables outside plugin. Is there no other way?

Comment: The problem is caused by $wrapper isn't the same everytime when you use $('') to create wrapper. so the $wrapper run by script and console are not the same one. And another problem is. when you start(). you need to stop() counter called before. or you will loss the setInterval id to stop it.

Comment: So, if you want to record data on element, please either use .attr() or https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/. Or they won't behave correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistake on your code.

1. you can't save data on $wrapper. Since they are recreated everytime.
2. you need to stop old interval before make a new, or you will lose the id to stop it.
3. don't pollute the wrapper, they can cause problem. for example.
   If later, a animation function want to use .stop() to stop the animate, they will found they can't stop that

   ;(function($, f) {
     $.fn.pluginName= function(o) {
       var $wrapper = this;

   ```
   /* don't save data on wrapper object directly*/
   function interval (data) {
     if (data) {
       $wrapper.data('interval', data);
     } else {
       return $wrapper.data('interval');
     }

   }

   var init = function(o) {
     if (!o || o === 'start') {
       start();
     } else {
       stop();
     }
     return $wrapper;
   };

   /*don't pollute wrapper, use option to switch instead*/

   function start() {
     /* you must stop old interval first*/
     stop();

     console.log('started')
     interval(setInterval(function() {
       console.log(1)
     }, 1000));
   };

   //  Stop autoplay
   function stop() {
     console.log('stoped')
     clearInterval(interval());
     return $wrapper;
   };
   return init(o);
   ```

   };
   })(window.jQuery, false);
   var i = $('.banner').pluginName();
   $('.banner').pluginName('stop');

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `this.interval` outside of `this.start` so that `$ wrapper.interval` is accessible throughout the plugin and not just in `this.start` :

```
$.fn.pluginName= function(o) {
        var $wrapper = this; 
        var init = function(o) {
            $wrapper.start();
            return $wrapper;
        };
        this.interval;
        this.start = function() {
            $wrapper.interval = setInterval(function() {
          console.log(1)
            }, 1000);
        };

        //  Stop autoplay
        this.stop = function() {
        console.log(2)
        clearInterval($wrapper.interval);
            return $wrapper;
        };
      return init(o);
```